# Ethsigner v22.1.3 - -32700 Parse Error on any calls

Tags: ethsigner

I am running ethsigner/v22.1.3/windows-x86_64/oracle-java.

Here's my command to start ethsigner to connect to Ropsten

```
d:\Projects\Ethsigner\ethsigner-22.1.3\bin\ethsigner --chain-id=3 --downstream-http-host=ropsten.infura.io --downstream-http-path=/v3/<my key> --downstream-http-port=443 --downstream-http-tls-enabled file-based-signer --key-file=d:\Projects\Ethsigner\keyfile --password-file=d:\projects\Ethsigner\password
```

And this is my curl command

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[],"id":51}' http://127.0.0.1:8545
```

And here's my error on Ethsigner:

```
2022-04-07 21:45:50.768+08:00 | vert.x-worker-thread-0 | INFO  | JsonRpcHandler | Dropping request from 127.0.0.1:56288
```

And this is my error on curl

```
{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":null,"error":{"code":-32700,"message":"Parse error"}}
```

I don't seem to be able to run any transactions on my Ethsigner instance. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by running the command in Postman instead of curl. If you are on windows, do not use the curl command:

```
curl -X POST --data '{"jsonrpc":"2.0","method":"eth_blockNumber","params":[],"id":51}' http://127.0.0.1:8545
```

Instead, go to Use Postman (https://www.postman.com/) to send a post request with the following as Body

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "method": "eth_blockNumber",
    "params": [],
    "id": 51
}
```